# Problems CMD Executing Maven Program

Tags: tomcat, maven, netbeans, build, cmd

I have a maven project I developed in my ofice ... Today I wanted to use it in home! Apache-tomcat ints installed and I tryed to run the project in Netbeans.

The project build its sueccessfull but just after netbeans end the building show me this message ""cmd" is not recognized as an internal or external command, program or batch file."
After that nothing happen no browser no error ... nothing!

Its seems it could be a problem with the system variables ?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Not enough information to begin to help. Sounds like your build is running an executable that is missing on your machine. This is highly unusual as most Maven builds would execute Java code within the same JVM running Maven.

Comment: Maybe different OS home/office?

Comment: And hows that becoming a problem ? Yes in the ofice I use Ubuntu and Windows in home! but cant see the diference! And Mark what else can I tell you to make this problem more clear ?

Comment: How about posting the last few lines from Netbeans console, as well as  what command you are running in netbeans?